# j2me - random number - card game

Tags: java, java-me, random

I am trying to generate 5 different random numbers for use in my card game app, so far i am using a while loop as follows which prints out 5 of the same number, i am wondering how to make 5 DIFFERENT random numbers, surely it cant be much different to the code i have so far....

```
 int n = 0;

 while(n<5)

{

 Random r = new Random();

 int i = r.nextInt(10);

 System.out.println( i);  

 n++;

 }
```

I hope somebody can help :-)

x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `Random r = new Random();` outside of your while loop.

The seed is based on the timestamp:

> Two Random objects created within the same millisecond will have the same sequence of random numbers.

[(reference)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29)

Since you're not doing much inside your loop it's not taking more than a millisecond between calls, which means that each `new Random()` is initialized with the same seed.